# Center Pie Chart in SVG Element

Tags: d3.js

I've already read:

1. https://bl.ocks.org/mbostock/3887235
2. http://zeroviscosity.com/d3-js-step-by-step/step-1-a-basic-pie-chart
3. [Center align a pie chart on svg](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34418531/center-align-a-pie-chart-on-svg)

Consider the following:

```js
var dataAsCsv = `Col1,Col2
Type1,123456
Type2,789012
Type3,34567`;

var data = d3.csvParse(dataAsCsv);

var margin = {top: 50, right: 20, bottom: 50, left: 80},
    width = 1400 - margin.left - margin.right,
    height = 700 - margin.top - margin.bottom;

var svgPie = d3.select('body').append('svg')
  .attr("width", width + margin.left + margin.right)
  .attr("height", height + margin.top + margin.bottom);
   
var gPie = svgPie.append("g")
           .attr("transform", "translate(" + margin.left + "," + margin.top + ")");
     
var radius = Math.min(width, height) / 2;

var color = d3.scaleOrdinal(d3.schemeCategory20b);
   
var label = d3.arc()
    .outerRadius(radius - 40)
    .innerRadius(radius - 40);

var path = d3.arc()
    .outerRadius(radius - 10)
    .innerRadius(0);

var pie = d3.pie()
   .value(function(d) { return d.Col2; })
   .sort(null);

var arc = gPie.selectAll(".arc")
    .data(pie(data))
    .enter().append("g")
      .attr("class", "arc");
   
arc.append("path")
      .attr("d", path)
      .attr("fill", function(d) { return color(d.data.Col1); });
   
arc.append("text")
      .attr("transform", function(d) { return "translate(" + label.centroid(d) + ")"; })
      .attr("dy", "0.35em")
      .text(function(d) { return d.data.Col1; });
```

```html
<script src="https://d3js.org/d3.v4.js"></script>
```

I am trying to center the pie chart vertically and horizontally with respect to the entire svg element that it is in. I tried modifying my code to the examples above to no avail.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You just have to translate the parent `g` element at half width horizontally and at half height vertically:

Instead of:

```
var gPie = svgPie.append("g")
           .attr("transform", "translate(" + margin.left + "," + margin.top + ")");
```

write:

```
var gPie = svgPie.append("g")
           .attr("transform", "translate(" + width/2 + "," + height/2 + ")");
```

Check the demo:

```js
var dataAsCsv = `Col1,Col2
Type1,123456
Type2,789012
Type3,34567`;

var data = d3.csvParse(dataAsCsv);

var margin = {top: 50, right: 20, bottom: 50, left: 80},
    width = 1400 - margin.left - margin.right,
    height = 700 - margin.top - margin.bottom;

var svgPie = d3.select('body').append('svg')
  .attr("width", width + margin.left + margin.right)
  .attr("height", height + margin.top + margin.bottom);
   
var gPie = svgPie.append("g")
           .attr("transform", "translate(" + width/2 + "," + height/2 + ")");
     
var radius = Math.min(width, height) / 2;

var color = d3.scaleOrdinal(d3.schemeCategory20b);
   
var label = d3.arc()
    .outerRadius(radius - 40)
    .innerRadius(radius - 40);

var path = d3.arc()
    .outerRadius(radius - 10)
    .innerRadius(0);

var pie = d3.pie()
   .value(function(d) { return d.Col2; })
   .sort(null);

var arc = gPie.selectAll(".arc")
    .data(pie(data))
    .enter().append("g")
      .attr("class", "arc");
   
arc.append("path")
      .attr("d", path)
      .attr("fill", function(d) { return color(d.data.Col1); });
   
arc.append("text")
      .attr("transform", function(d) { return "translate(" + label.centroid(d) + ")"; })
      .attr("dy", "0.35em")
      .text(function(d) { return d.data.Col1; });
```

```html
<script src="https://d3js.org/d3.v4.js"></script>
```